# Trigger for field update on related object based on opportunity stage

Tags: apex, trigger

I created a custom object budget and create a lookup relationship with opportunity. So one budget lookup field on opportunity and update this field according to close date via trigger. If close date within month of Jan so budget field update as “Jan”. So all Jan close date opportunity come under Jan budget.

My requirement is when any opportunity stage change as close won so opportunities amount should be some and populate on custom field “won amount “ on budget object. Same with open opportunities all open opportunities amount should show on “pipeline amount” custom field.
I think trigger would be good approach but I don’t know how to query. Could you experts help me?

[image]

```
trigger updateField on Opportunity (after update) {

Map<Id,Decimal>  budgetIDTotalMap = new MAp<Id,Decimal>();  
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
{
      if(opp.stageName == 'ClosedWon'){
        Decimal t = 0;
        if(budgetIDTotalMap.containsKey(opp.budget__c) && budgetIDTotalMap.get(opp.budget__c) != null)
               t = budgetIDTotalMap.containsKey(opp.budget__c);
            budgetIDTotalMap.put(opp.budget__c,t+opp.Amount);
       }
}
List<Budget__c> blist = [select id,Won_Amount__c from budget__c where id in :budgetIDTotalMap.keySet()];
for(Budget__c c: blist)
{
if(budgetIDTotalMap.containskey(c.id))
{
  c.Won_Amount__c += budgetIDTotalMap.get(c.id);
}
}

 if(blist.size()>0)
 update blist;
}
```

Comment: I presume you can't use the stand roll up summary field due it not be

Comment: Being a master detail relationship. There are several roll up summary helper classes available that you could leverage for example http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/07/new-tool-declarative-rollups-for-lookups/ (sorry for typos, on mobile)

Comment: Yes if possible because I am not able to think the logic. how can I count Amount as per stage?

Comment: I am getting error  Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Boolean to Decimal at line 9 column 20  t = budgetIDTotalMap.containsKey(opp.budget__c); @Ratan

Comment: I think error is with decimal. I tried with t.intValue(); but no luck.

Comment: That error message is because you used containsKey() instead of get()

Comment: I changed containsKey( ) to get( ) and Code is working now but is is calculating double amount. let say if won amount are 1000 so it is showing 2000. @ratan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can get all the budget Id and based on that get all the opportunity where `stageName = ClosedWon`. Use aggregate query to get the some of Amount..

```
trigger updateField on Opportunity (after update) {

    Map<Id,Decimal>  budgetIDTotalMap = new MAp<Id,Decimal>();  
    set<id> setbudgetId = new set<Id>();

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(opp.stageName == 'ClosedWon' && opp.budget__c != null){
            setbudgetId.add(opp.budget__c);
        }
    }

    for(AggregateResult objArg : [SELECT budget__c, SUM(Amount) total FROM Opportunity WHERE budget__c IN: setbudgetId AND stageName = 'ClosedWon' GROUP BY budget__c])
    {
        budgetIDTotalMap.put((Id)objArg.get('budget__c'), (Decimal)objArg.get('total'));
    }
    List<Budget__c> blist = [select id,Won_Amount__c from budget__c where id in :budgetIDTotalMap.keySet()];
    for(Budget__c c: blist)
    {
        if(budgetIDTotalMap.containskey(c.id))
        {
            c.Won_Amount__c = budgetIDTotalMap.get(c.id);
        }
    }
    update blist;
}
```